# how to create dev server on app-engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a server running on app-engine. I am working on version 2 of my server, which serves as the backend for a mobile app. How do I a dev and a staging server so that I can test before replacing the production server? Does anyone know of a tutorial somewhere that addresses exactly this issue? It would be nice if I could set things up the way Google Play sets up android publication: I can publish to Alpha; then move the apk to Beta; and then to production. I will take what I can get at this point, but that structure would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement using http://www.streamhead.com/google-appengine-staging-server/. It's better than versioning. But thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [versions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_System_properties_and_environment_variables) for this purpose. This way you can talk to myApp.appspot.com for a "production" version, to beta.myApp.appspot.com for a beta version, etc.

EDIT:

All versions run in different instances, but they all talk to the same datastore. It is a good option to test changes that do not break your data model - i.e. a beta version does not make changes in the datastore that break the production version.

Comment: This is interesting, but it's not clear how it would work. so If I push `beta.myapp.appspot.com`, are you certain that it does not replace the production version that I have serving? Does it use the same datastore? What if I change some entities and delete others?

Comment: If you deploy a new version with a different version id, like "beta", it will not be a default version. It will be accessible via a different URL, and it will run of different instances from your production version. It will access the same datastore. I also updated my response.

Comment: thanks for helping. +1. See my response for what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test it in a local environment before pushing it to app engine. I would recommend have a separate box/server and deploy your code there and run the application on that server. Run application as web application in debug mode so you can see errors or problems that occurs. Connect your phone via Wi-Fi to your LAN and make sure the port you are using such as 8080 is open in your hub/firewall.

This way your server's services can send data and receive data without actually deploying on app engine.

This link might be useful:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver